# How to pass pointer to a reference as an argument to a function-Objective C

Tags: objective-c

In C++ we will pass the pointer to a function as

```
bool getData(REMOTE_ID msId,RsEvent*& pEvent);
```

How to declare this in Objective C?

```
// ?
-(BOOL)getData:(REMOTE_ID)msId withEvent:(RsEvent*)pEvent;
```

But i need to use the pointer to reference (`RsEvent*&`). I have used only pointer (`RsEvent*`) as a datatype here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use pointers to simulate reference in C (and Objective-C):

```
-(BOOL)getData:(REMOTE_ID)msId withEvent:(RsEvent**)pEvent {
   // do stuff with msId and *pEvent
}
```

and pass in the argument as a pointer:

```
RsEvent* event;
BOOl res = [foo getData:msId withEvent:&event];
...
```

Answer (score 1):

(By the way, you're not dealing with a pointer to a reference, but a reference to a pointer.) Can't you just use the same type annotation in the Objective-C method?

```
- (BOOL)getData:(REMOTE_ID)msId withEvent:(RsEvent*&)pEvent;
```

I think that should work, but if it doesn't, you can use a pointer to a pointer instead:

```
- (BOOL)getData:(REMOTE_ID)msId withEvent:(RsEvent**)pEvent {
  useEvent(*pEvent); // when using the event, you need to dereference the pointer
}
```

Send the `-getData:withEvent:` message with the **address** of your event:

```
[obj getData:SOME_ID withEvent:&event];
```

Comment: @kennyTm @Jonathan: I will try using the declaration.Thanks for helping me understand.I need to get clear with the pointer concepts well.